# flask-opencv-streamer werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'calc'. Did you mean 'static' instead?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, pytorch

I am trying to figure out how to actually run the flask-opencv-streamer python module properly, I am currently trying to run the example given here without authentication : https://pypi.org/project/flask-opencv-streamer/

I've attached the error here :
https://pasteboard.co/Iso8Z3C.png

Comment: Please put the stacktrace in the question, and any relevant code. External image hosting sites may be blocked for certain users (myself included)

Comment: please add full code

Comment: from flask_opencv_streamer.streamer import Streamer
import cv2

port = 3030
require_login = False
streamer = Streamer(port, require_login)

# Open video device 0
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = video_capture.read()

    streamer.update_frame(frame)

    if not streamer.is_streaming:
        streamer.start_streaming()

    cv2.waitKey(30)